# pyspark dataframe.where unexpectedly returning nothing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I have a dataframe that contains some stock data, and I am making a subset of this data that has a certain amount of entries using a left semi join. The Name column contains stocks tickers.

```
ser = traindf.groupBy('Name').count().where(("count == 1006"))
selected_stocks = traindf.join(ser, ['Name'], 'leftsemi')
```

traindf is the original training dataframe, which returns the expected results when I do

```
display(traindf.where('Name == "AMZN"'))
```

This returns all of the rows with name AMZN in the traindf. However, even though AMZN is in ser/selected_stocks, when I do

```
display(selected_stocks.where('Name == "AMZN"'))
```

or

```
display(ser.where('Name == "AMZN"'))
```

It says "Query returned no results".
But it does return the values for AMZN, along with the rest of the stocks whos tickers start with A if I do

```
display(selected_stocks.filter(col('Name').like('A%'))
```

I need to select the stocks like this, by their ticker, for a function I am running on them. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could point me in the right direction of why it wont let me directly specify the ticker.

I already tried running a left semi join on some dummy data, similar to how I did it here, and use where to select data, but It worked as expected.

EDIT: I couldn't figure out what was wrong so I just used pandas for the left semi join section then put the dataframe back into a spark dataframe and it works. Very wierd.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the whether column- Name  does not contains spaces.

you can try below :

df1=selected_stocks.withColumn('Name',trim(selected_stocks.Name))

df1.where('Name == "AMZN"').show()

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is still showing only column names and no rows after this.